# Check if Columns Value is in One Specific Column With Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

So I have one dataframe which has multiple columns and I want to try to find out if the values in my "**Linked..**" columns is in column called "**New Names**", and if it is then that specific cell value should be set in such way "cell.value - Yes" or if not that "cell.value - No"

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'New Names': ['a,b,c','a','c,d,e,f','a'], 'Linked Letter 0': 
['a','b','c','d'],
'Linked Letter 1': ['c','s','v','None'],
'Linked Letter 2': ['None','None','d','s']}

df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_new


      Index   New Names   Linked Letter 0   Linked Letter 1   Linked Letter 2  
     ------- ----------- ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- 
        0       a,b,c       a                 c                 None             
        1       a           b                 s                 None             
        2       c,d,e,f     c                 v                 d                
        3       a           d                 None              s
```

So expected result should be as following table;

```
    Index   New Names   Linked Letter 0   Linked Letter 1   Linked Letter 2  
    ------- ----------- ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- 
    0        a,b,c         a - YES           c - YES           None             
    1        a             b - NO            s - NO            None             
    2        c,d,e,f       c - YES           v - NO            d - YES          
    3        a             d - NO            None              s - NO
```

**One Problem with the solution provided below:**

The problem is that mapping to YES and NO to values sometimes don't work as expected. For instance, same value which gets YES at the end can get NO in the next row even though the value in New Names column is same in both rows.

Why do you think this would occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter your `Linked` columns, a list comprehension to construct a Boolean array, and finally [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for your conditional logic:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

for col in df.filter(like='Linked'):
    bools = [link in new_names for link, new_names in zip(df[col], df['New Names'])]
    df.loc[df[col] != 'None', col] += pd.Series(np.where(bools, ' - YES', ' - NO'))

print(df)

  Linked Letter 0 Linked Letter 1 Linked Letter 2 New Names
0         a - YES         c - YES            None     a,b,c
1          b - NO          s - NO            None         a
2         c - YES          v - NO         d - YES   c,d,e,f
3          d - NO            None          s - NO         a
```

Comment: although it works as it should however there are some cases where the boolean array populates the wrong tag (YES, NO) and this happens to even exactly the same values. for example in some rows you find one item in New Names column and attach "Yes" value and for the same item in different row it attaches "No" even though value is in New Names column

Comment: @iSerd, Sorry, I don't follow. Would you like to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54090823/edit) with data which does *not* work with my proposed solution?

Comment: Hi @jpp, I just updated the entry with my question thanks for your consideration

Comment: @iSerd, Sorry, I meant change your input, give a **[mcve]**, i.e. input where my logic does *not* work. It works with the input you've provided.

Comment: Actually if i try to re-construct the data by myself then your solution works however I need to process the data before to get this version I provided in my question and I can't share the actual data (confidential) so I believe it must be something related to data type issue or sth (I already checked the type of data where i have the wrong mapping for Yes and No) - do you think of any other possible problem here? because that's so weird that it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Comment: @iSerd, Possibly. But that's a different question. For an answer to your new question, I suggestion you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a [mcve]. Otherwise, I (or anyone else) is just guessing.

Comment: Thank you! I will do that way. Cheers